# Insert bar graph in Prawn pdf

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, prawn

I am using Prawn to generate pdfs reports.
I need to put in my report a simple bar graph. Currently what is the best way to insert a graph in a prawn pdf ?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways you might insert a bar graph using Prawn:

1. Try the [prawn-graph](https://github.com/HHRy/prawn-graph/) gem
2. Use the [Prawn Graphics API](http://prawnpdf.org/api-docs/2.0/Prawn/Graphics.html) to draw rectangles, lines, and text yourself
3. Find an SVG graph/chart library you like, render the graph in SVG, and then use [prawn-svg](https://github.com/mogest/prawn-svg) to insert the SVG into your PDF